# PHP Encoding of Special Characters iso-8859-1

Tags: php, character-encoding

My PHP script parses a web site and pulls out an HTML DIV that looks like this (and saves it as a string)

```
<div id="merchantinfo">The following merchants: Nautica®, Brookstone®, Teds® ©2012 Blabla</div>
```

I store this as $merchantList (string).

However, when I output the data to the webpage

```
echo $merchantList
```

The encoding gets messed up and displays as:

```
NauticaÃ‚Â®, BrookstoneÃ‚Â®, TedsÃ‚Â® Â©2012 Blabla
```

I tried adding the following to the display page:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
```

But that didn't do anything.  --Thanks

**EDIT::** ------------

For the question, the accepted answer is correct.

But I realized my actual issue was slightly different.

The initial parsing using DOMDocument::loadHTML had already mangled the UTF-8 encoding, causing the string to save as

```
<div id="merchantinfo">The following merchants: NauticaÃ®, BrookstoneÃ®, TedsÃ® ©2012 Blabla</div>
```

This was solved by:

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

And do not use iso-8859-1. Use UTF-8.

From the mojibake you posted the input string is utf-8, not iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

You need just to Use [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) function , exemple :

```
$string = '&quot;hello dude&quot;';
$decodechars = htmlspecialchars_decode($string);
echo $decodechars; // output : "hello dude"
```